# javascript to redirect page pased on selected value

Tags: javascript, select, redirect, window.location

I am try to redirect the page depending on whether the users selects 'standard' or 'maintenance' in a drop down menu. Hoewever my javascript isn't quite working. Can you help point me where I'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function formType(value){
        if (value == 'maintenance') {
            window.location = "index.php?requestType=maintenance";
        } else {
            window.location = "index.php?requestType=standard";
        }
    -->
    </script>
    <select id="changer" name="type" onchange="formType(this.value);">
              <option value="standard" <?php if ($requestType == 'standard') { echo "selected"; } ?>>Standard</option>
              <option value="maintenance" <?php if ($requestType == 'maintenance') { echo "selected"; } ?>>Maintenance</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: `function formType(value) { window.location = "index.php?requestType=" + value; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `}` at the end of your function.

Comment: Thank you! I feel dumb now for missing something so simple...

Answer (score 0):

There's a `}` missing at the end of your function. It should look like this :

```
function formType(value){
    if (value == 'maintenance') {
        window.location = "index.php?requestType=maintenance";
    } else {
        window.location = "index.php?requestType=standard";
    }
}
```